# Restore Window Size on Redirect from PopUp

Tags: javascript, redirect, asp-classic, popup

There is probably a simple solution for this, but I don't know what it is.  I have a pop-up window in which I perform a standard Response.Redirect to a new page, based upon a radio-button selection.  Everything works as expected, but the new page is the same size as the pop-window (as it is appearing IN the same pop-up window).  How would I go about making the new page appear as a normal page and not in the pop-up window?

```
function EditOrder(f) {

var orderid_values = document.getElementsByName('OrderIDValues');
var orderid_value;

    for(var i = 0; i < orderid_values.length; i++){
        if(orderid_values[i].checked){
        orderid_value = orderid_values[i].value;
        }
    }

    window.open("/memberlogin/orders/editorderpopup.asp?cert=<%=sCertificate%>&loginid=<%=iSessID%>&cid=<%=iCustomerID%>&oid=" + orderid_value,"dialogCancelOrder","resizable=0,scrollbars=yes,location=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,top=200,left=500,width=900,height=900")

} 
</script>
```

Then, in the EDITORDERPOPUP.ASP page, the following redirect occurs based upon the radio button selected (this is just a snippet out of the page):

```
' Based upon the radio button value (1,2,3.., etc.), call the EDITORDER.ASP page with the "editmode" = to the same value:

sURL = sRootDomain & "/administration/manualordering/editorder.asp?cert=" & sCertificate & "&loginID=" & iSessID & "&EditMode=" & RadioButtonValue
```

The new page is then displayed in the popup window.  I would like the new page to be a completely new window, or be a full window.

Comment: would you mind to share some code with us?

Comment: Absolutely!  I just didn't figure that code was needed in this case.  I guess that's why somebody gave me a negative 1.  I'll work on this immediately.

Comment: You might want to add some expected behaviour, such as if you want the popup window to still exist after you've been redirected, or if you want the window to be closed. Or if you want the popup window to be resized to "normal" size and then open it in that window. You have to remember that browsers remember your window size history so if you expect it to open in a certain height and width you may need to tell the new window to resize.

Comment: @DanielNordh Thank you for your reply.  I believe what you are saying, is exactly correct, and that is "You might want to add some expected behaviour..."  Indeed, after the redirect, I do NOT want to popup to exist any longer.  How is that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Response.Redirect` will always occur in same window/tab, so to redirect to another window/tab you should use *client* and not *server* scripting.

Example:

Master page that opens popup using client `<script>`

```
<button onclick="popup()">Open popup</button> 
<script> 
    function popup() {
        window.open('popup.asp', '', 'height=400,width=400');
    }
</script>
```

popup.asp that has nothing but client `<script>`

```
<input type="radio" id="a" name="r1" onclick="win1()" />
<input type="radio" id="b" name="r1" onclick="win2()" />

<script>
    function win1() {
        window.open('https://stackoverflow.com');
    }
    function win2() {
        window.open('https://microsoft.com');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hello Alex.  Thank you for your post.  I think what you are saying here is to NOT use Response.Redirect, and instead use Javascript for the page redirection.  I'll try this ASAP and come back and update.  Thank you!